# api covid on android studio using retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I'm trying to retrieve some data covid API from the **https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all** API, this data i want to get: **{"updated":1656205927696,"deaths":6350239,"recovered":523475632}**.
but always error if I put the data into textview, is there a solution to this problem?

here my `MainActivity.class`  this is where the error problem occurs:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.apicovid, PID: 1898
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.apicovid.Model.getDeaths()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.apicovid.MainActivity$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:30)
```

```
package com.example.apicovid;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private  final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTextView =  findViewById(R.id.jmlh);
        getDataApi();
    }

    private void getDataApi() {
        APIService.api().getData()
                .enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            String totalcases = String.valueOf(response.body().getUpdated());
                            mTextView.setText("COde: "+ totalcases);
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
    }
}
```

---

this my `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/jmlh"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

this my `API interface`

```
package com.example.apicovid;


import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface API {
    @GET("all")
    Call<Model> getData();
}
```

---

this is my `Model.class`

```
package com.example.apicovid;

public class Model {
    private String updated,deaths,recovered;

    public String getUpdated() {
        return updated;
    }

    public void setUpdated(String updated) {
        this.updated = updated;
    }

    public String getDeaths() {
        return deaths;
    }

    public void setDeaths(String deaths) {
        this.deaths = deaths;
    }

    public String getRecovered() {
        return recovered;
    }

    public void setRecovered(String recovered) {
        this.recovered = recovered;
    }
}
```

---

this is my `APIService.class`

```
package com.example.apicovid;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class APIService {
    private static String BASE_URL = "https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    public static API api(){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(API.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Put a break point on if `(!response.isSuccessful()) {` and check that the response is what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

it worked, where is my error, which is putting this line of code   `String totalcases = String.valueOf(response.body().getUpdated());`
inside `if (!response.isSuccessful()) {}` and I tried to put it outside the if and the data was successfully retrieved from the API